# Unable to parse Json as a Map - Scala/Play

Tags: json, scala, dictionary, playframework

I'm unable to parse the json I'm getting as a Map. Anyone have any ideas? Please do ask if you require any more information. Thanks :)

Trying to parse the following response using:

```
Json.parse(response.body).as[Map[String, Either[List[ErrorMsg], Seq[OepPoint]]]]
```

Response:

```
{
  "Payout": {
    "errors":[
      {
        "field": "Last point: OepPoint(0.033,72.14). Current: OepPoint(0.033,65.71)",
        "message":"OEP must be unique"
      }
    ],
    "curve":[]
  }
}
```

Error Message thrown is:

```
No Json deserializer found for type Map[String,Either[List[ErrorMsg],Seq[OepPoint]]]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
[error]     val errorExpected = Json.parse(response.body).as[Map[String, Either[List[ErrorMsg], Seq[OepPoint]]]]
[error]                                                     ^
[error] one error found
```

Structure of OepPoint:

```
case class OepPoint(oep: Double, loss: Double)

object OepPoint {
   implicit val oepPointReads = Json.format[OepPoint]
 }
```

Structure of ErrorMsg:

```
case class ErrorMsg(field: String, message: String)

object ErrorMsg {
  implicit val errorMsgReads = Json.format[ErrorMsg]
}
```

Comment: Can you format things to be bit more readable.

Comment: Play-json provides `Read`s for common types such as `String`, `Int`, `List[ A ]` etc. In case of generic types like `List[ A ]`, `implicit Read` for `A` will be required. You will have to provide `implicit` `Read`s for your own types. Which are - probably `OepPoint` and `ErrorMsg`.

Comment: I assume that the way I have defined my OepPoint atm is wrong?
`case class OepPoint(oep: Double, loss: Double)

object OepPoint {
  implicit val oepPointReads = Json.format[OepPoint]
}`

Comment: Just define a `Read` for your JSON structure. `as[Map[String, Either[List[ErrorMsg], Seq[OepPoint]]]]` won't work even if proper reads for `ErrorMsg` and `OepPoint` were provided.

Comment: I did try that, that doesn't work either :/ Unless I've done it wrong, which is highly probable.
`case class EpCurveResults(value: Map[String, Either[List[ErrorMsg], Seq[OepPoint]]])

object EpCurveResults {
  implicit val epCurveResultsReads = Json.format[EpCurveResults]
}`

Comment: Your JSON structure is actually a `Map[ String, Map[ String, List[ Any ] ]`. Assuming that `OepPoint` and `ErrorMsg` have no common parent type other than `Any`. That is why, it wont work as you  are providing in-compatible type.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of these classes? The play-json library does not know how to parse something into `Either[A, B]`, so you'll have to create that logic yourself.

Comment: Added them in. @SarveshKumarSingh, I'm not sure how to go about dealing with List[Any] :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have proper `Read`s for `OepPoint` and `ErrorMsg`. You can do following.

```
case class ErrOrOep( errors: List[ ErrorMsg ], curve: List[ OepPoint ] )

implcit val errOrOepFormat = Json.format[ ErrOrOep ]

val jsonMap = Json.parse(response.body).as[ Map[String, ErrOrOep ] ]

val errOrOep = jsonMap( "Payout" )

val oepEither: Either[ List[ ErrorMsg ], List[ OepPoint ] ] = 
  ( errOrOep.errors, errOrOep.curve ) match {
    case ( _, h :: _ ) => Right( errOrOep.curve )
    case ( h :: _, _  ) => Left( errOrOep.error )
    case ( _, _ ) => Left( errOrOep.error )
  }
```